# Spring security requestmatcher enable swagger api download endpoint returns 401

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, openapi

I configured my openAPI endpoints so that I can download my swagger yml files on /docs.yml
I enabled the following:

```
.requestMatchers("/docs/**").permitAll()
```

I also tried

```
.requestMatchers("/docs.yml").permitAll()
.requestMatchers("/docs/**").permitAll()
```

Is there a way to enable the download of the file as well the endpoints under /docs/ ?

EDIT:

I'm using sping boot 3. Based on the docs, I have to include

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

for openApi support

Comment: Have you tried using `.requestMatchers(AntPathRequestMatcher.antMatcher("/docs**"));`?

Comment: Yes. With the config in my post I can reach everythin but the /docs.yml With /docs** every /docs eindpoint is forbidden.

Comment: @FishingIsLife Did you read: https://springdoc.org/v2/#spring-security-support Maybe it is missing?